# Vaadin 14 - Disable Hovering Response on Buttons

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

Is it possible to disable the hovering functionality for Buttons? I haven't come across any methods that facilitate this, so I'm guessing writing a custom function might be required here.

Comment: What exactly do you want to disable? Do you have an example?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli when you hover over a button, say with a Lumo Primary theme design, there is a slight change in color until you move outside the button area again

Comment: You have to change the button CSS. I will add an example tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the hover with CSS.

Add CSS file with this content. opacity: 0 will disable the change on hover.

```
:host(:hover)::before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then you have to import it for the vaadin-button like this:

```
@CssImport(value = "./themes/vaadindemo/components/button.css", themeFor = "vaadin-button")
```

Please find a running example here:

https://github.com/simasch/vaadin-examples